# How multi-hop bots finds the best way?

Tags: solidity, flashbots, trading

I have seen many bots perform multi-hop swaps to get the best arbitrage opportunity. So how do they find a such best path & exchange for their multi-hop swaps which gives the best returns?
For eg Pancakeswap achieves multihop using Uniswap v3 router. So how does it do that?

Answer (score 0):

For the most part it's likely private, proprietary code that finds deep (multi-hop) arbitrage opportunities in efficient ways. There is probably also a bit of people leeching from services like Matcha and 1inch which are good at finding efficient ways between assets, sometimes showing arbitrage opportunities